# How to I get a PlayBack to be refreshed in Coded UI Test?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I'm running a coded ui test on a WPF window.
The accessibility \ automationpeer of one of the controls was not well implemented.

I want to be able to open the window, run some tests like clicking buttons and insert text to some textboxes. Than, I want to refresh the map, in other words to reselect the problematic control as if the CUIT (coded ui test builder) was running and i dragged the crosshair on the control. I want to get a new instance of the automationpeer of the control, not the old one.

Comment: UIMap...UIYourControl.Find() should do the trick. It throws the cached version away and redoes the search.

Comment: You could also set the always search configuration. control.SearchConfigurations.Add(SearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch);